# android proxy and exception list configuration

Tags: android

We are facing issue regarding proxy and exception list  configuration on the Taztag Android device . we want to use intranet  application and internet application at same time . there is a proxy to use the external application but after configuring proxy all data is going to proxy only so we want to use exception for internal applications .

1. We are using  proxy on the APN of the device but there is no option to configure exception list on the device .
2. We are using Mozila firefox and there is option to configure proxy and exception list but that configuration is not taking effect on the device .

Need your suggestion and support for some possible solution .